# Google App Engine Task Has Time Limit of 5 seconds?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am adding some tasks to a job in Google App Engine.

They seem to timeout after 5 seconds.  But they need 20 seconds to run.

How can I increase the timeout?

Comment: What language are you using, and where is your code?

Comment: A task on a front end have a timeout of 10 minutes and is unlimited on a back end.
How do you put your job into a queue ? Do you user deferred tasks ?

Comment: My code is on the app engine. I am using Python.  An example call is taskqueue.add( url='/hl', deadline=60)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the named queue GAE select automaticaly the default Queue.
To change the default queue settings you need to create a file queue.yaml like this:

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 2/m
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
    task_age_limit: 10m
```

To use a named Queue you can call the Queue like this

```
my_queue = taskqueue.Queue('usage')
my_task = taskqueue.add(url='/usage_worker', params={'uid': uid, 'usage': usage})
my_queue.add(my_task)
```

and add the entry in the queue.yaml file

```
- name: usage
  rate: 5/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 1
    task_age_limit: 10m
```

[GAE doc about Task Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/?hl=fr)